# merging data from 2 databases

Tags: sql, database

Currently have a contracts system that pulls in job data from our finance system.  Each job has an id and the contracts hang off of that.  We now have to bring in job data from another finance system.  The jobs from the new system will also contain a job id and contracts will have to hang from this.  I expect there will be some id conflicts when the data is merged.  Whats the best way to deal with this.  Should I create another table that pulls in the job data from both and assigns a new id for the contracts to hang from.  Obviously I will need to update the current contracts to match the new id's generated.  Does this sound like a good idea or is there a better way.

Comment: Is this a one-time merge or do you need to perform this process regularly? Which RDBMS are you using? Can the same job appear in both systems? If that happens what do you do about it? I think that your question is a bit too high-level to really get a definitive answer on what will work best.

Comment: sorry, its not a one time thing.  The system will need to work with both systems.  The original will be phased out early next year but will be available in a read only format.  The same job wont appear in both systems.  I dont think its to high level.  Im asking how i should handle data that potentially could have primary key conflicts.  The RDBMS im using is sqlserver.  one 2000 and one 2008

Answer (score 0):

Given your additional comments, I would suggest that you use a mapping table to map any of the conflicting IDs in the old system to new IDs. Normally when importing data into an existing system you would want to keep the IDs of the current system intact, but since that system is going to be gone in a year (or however long it takes) and is about to be read only I would think that you would want to try to preserve IDs in the new system.

Once you create the mapping table, you would then use that to update any foreign key references, etc. and then import the new data, which should now have no conflicts.